# Portable library doesn't build with Code contracts

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, code-contracts

I'm trying to build a wp8.1+win8.1 portable class library with enabled Runtime checking Code contracts, but it fails with the following error:
Reading assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' from '..packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' resulted in errors.
Could not resolve type reference: [mscorlib]System.IConvertible

What can be done about this?
Thanks!